# how to set strikethrough effects for cell with Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel?

Tags: php, laravel-excel

I'm using  Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel to export xlsx file. 
How to set strikethrough for cell like image

[image]

I have read document but can't resolve.

My code (not work):

```
    $sheet->cells("I5", function($cells) {
                $cells->setFont(array(
                    // 'underline'       =>  true
                    'strikethrough'=>true

                ));

            });
```

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, you can style your Cell or Stylesheet (https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/blade/styling.html) :

```
// Set font with ->setStyle()`
$sheet->setStyle(array(
    'font' => array(
        'name'      =>  'Calibri',
        'size'      =>  12,
        'bold'      =>  true,
        'strikethrough' => true,
    )
));
```

It uses PhpOffice / Spreadsheet, so look the doc of this plugin : https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/

Comment: could you help on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376745/laravel-excel-style-with-css-not-working-while-exporting-view