# Cannot use object of type App\Exports\OffetTableExport as array - Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I am working on multiple sheets on laravel excel. And, I am exporting data on two sheets using two export. But, half of the data to pushed on 2nd sheets will be generated in 1st export. So I am having difficulties in passing this data from 1st expor to second sheets. This could be further clarified with the code given below:

**mainExport**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class FloorPlanExport implements WithMultipleSheets
{
    protected $property, $mapped_columns;

    public function __construct($property, $mapped_columns)
    {
        $this->property = $property;
        $this->mapped_columns = $mapped_columns;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        $offset = new OffsetSummaryExport($this->property);
        $resp_data = new OffetTableExport($this->property, $this->mapped_columns);
        $offset_summary = $offset + $resp_data['summary'];

        $sheets = [
            $resp_data['table'],
            $offset_summary
        ];
        return $sheets;
    }


}
```

**exportRelatedToFirstSheet**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Helpers\SanitizeData;
use App\Models\FloorPlan;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;

class OffetTableExport implements FromArray
{
    protected $property, $mapped_columns;

    public function __construct($property, $mapped_columns)
    {
        $this->property = $property;
        $this->mapped_columns = $mapped_columns;
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        $floorPlans = FloorPlan::with(['unitTypeDetail'])
            ->where('property_id',$this->property->id)
            ->get();

        $items = [];
        $underCountArr = $overCountArr = [];
        $underChargeArr = $overChargeArr = [];
        foreach($floorPlans as $fk => $fp){
            $temp_items = [];
            if($fk === 0 ){
                if(in_array('pms_property',$this->mapped_columns)){
                    $temp_items['PMS Property'] = 'PMS Property';
                }
                $temp_items['PMS Unit Type'] = 'PMS Unit Type';

                if(in_array('description',$this->mapped_columns)){
                    $temp_items['Description'] = 'Description';
                }
                if(in_array('beds',$this->mapped_columns)){
                    $temp_items['Beds'] = 'Beds';
                }
                if(in_array('baths',$this->mapped_columns)){
                    $temp_items['Baths'] = 'Baths';
                }
                $temp_items['Sqft'] = 'Sqft';
                $temp_items['Unit Count'] = 'Unit Count';

                $temp_items['Unit Type'] = 'Unit Type';
                $temp_items['Base'] = 'Base';
                $temp_items['Affordable'] = 'Affordable';
                $temp_items['SqFtDiff'] = 'SqFtDiff';

                if(in_array('pricing_offset',$this->mapped_columns)){
                    $temp_items['Current Offset ($)'] = 'Current Offset ($)';
                }

                $temp_items['RPSF ($)'] = 'RPSF ($)';
                $temp_items['Recommended Offset ($)'] = 'Recommended Offset ($)';
                $items[] = $temp_items;
                $temp_items = [];
            }

            if($fp->affordable == 1){
                $sqftDiff = '';
                $rpsf = '';
                $offset = '';
            }else{
                if($fp->unitTypeDetail->base_sqft == null || $fp->sqft == null){
                    $sqftDiff = '';
                }else{
                    $sqftDiff = $fp->sqft - $fp->unitTypeDetail->base_sqft;
                }

                if($this->property->rate  === null || $sqftDiff === '' || $fp->unitTypeDetail->base_sqft === null){
                    $offset = '';

                }else{
                    $brpsf =  ($fp->unitTypeDetail->rent / $fp->unitTypeDetail->base_sqft);
                    $offset = $sqftDiff * $brpsf * ($this->property->rate/100);
                    //                                    $round_offset = round($offset,2);
                }

                if($fp->unitTypeDetail->rent  == null || $fp->sqft == null){
                    $rpsf = '';
                }else{
                    if($offset == ''){
                        $rpsf = $fp->unitTypeDetail->rent / $fp->sqft;
                    }else{
                        $rpsf = ($fp->unitTypeDetail->rent + $offset) / $fp->sqft;
                    }

                }
            }

            /** in_array test **/
            if(in_array('pms_property',$this->mapped_columns)){
                $temp_items['PMS Property'] = $fp->pms_property;
            }
            $temp_items['PMS Unit Type'] = $fp->pms_unit_type;

            if(in_array('description',$this->mapped_columns)){
                $temp_items['Description'] = $fp->description;
            }
            if(in_array('beds',$this->mapped_columns)){
                $temp_items['Beds'] = $fp->beds;
            }
            if(in_array('baths',$this->mapped_columns)){
                $temp_items['Baths'] = $fp->baths;
            }
            $temp_items['Sqft'] = $fp->sqft;
            $temp_items['Unit Count'] = $fp->unit_count;

            $temp_items['Unit Type'] = $fp->unitTypeDetail->unit_type;
            $temp_items['Base'] = ($fp->unitTypeDetail->base_floor_plan_id == $fp->id)?'x':'';
            $temp_items['Affordable'] = ($fp->affordable == 1)?'x':'';
            $temp_items['SqFtDiff'] = $sqftDiff;

            $pricingOffset = '';
            if(in_array('pricing_offset',$this->mapped_columns)){
                $pricingOffset = $fp->pricing_offset;
                $temp_items['Current Offset ($)'] = $pricingOffset;
            }

            $temp_items['RPSF ($)'] = empty($rpsf)?'-':round($rpsf, 2);
            $temp_items['Recommended Offset ($)'] = empty($offset)?'-':round($offset);

            if( (string)$temp_items['Current Offset ($)'] != "" && (string)$offset != ""){
                $diff = $pricingOffset - $offset;
                if($diff != 0){
                    if($diff > 0){
                        $overCountArr[] = $fp->unit_count;
                        $overChargeArr[] = $diff;
                    }else{
                        $underCountArr[] = $fp->unit_count;
                        $underChargeArr[] = abs($diff);
                    }
                }
            }

            $items[] = $temp_items;
        }



        /** Data useful for second sheet*/
        $underAverage = $overAverage = $over50Average = 0;
        $totalUnderCount = array_sum($underCountArr);
        $totalUnderImpact = 0;
        $allOverCountArr = [];
        for($i=0; $i<count($underCountArr); $i++){
            $totalUnderImpact += $underCountArr[$i] * $underChargeArr[$i];
        }
        if(!empty($totalUnderCount)){
            $underAverage = $totalUnderImpact/$totalUnderCount;
        }

        $totalOver50Count = $totalOver50Impact = 0;
        $totalOverCount = array_sum($overCountArr);
        $totalOverImpact = $over50CountArr = 0;
        for($i=0; $i<count($overCountArr); $i++){
            $totalOverImpact += $overCountArr[$i] * $overChargeArr[$i];
            if($overChargeArr[$i] > 50){
                $totalOver50Count += $overCountArr[$i];
                $totalOver50Impact += $overCountArr[$i] * $overChargeArr[$i];
            }
        }
        if(!empty($totalOverCount)){
            $overAverage = $totalOverImpact/$totalOverCount;
        }
        if(!empty($totalOver50Count)){
            $over50Average = $totalOver50Impact/$totalOver50Count;
        }

        /** Calculated data which  need to be shown in second sheet */
        $offset_summary = [
            ['UnderCharge'],
            ['Count', 'Average', 'Impact'],
            [$totalUnderCount, SanitizeData::currency(round(abs($underAverage))), SanitizeData::currency(round(abs($totalUnderImpact))) ], //just transform number to Currency
            [''],
            ['Affected Count', 'Per Unit Avg', 'Unit Count > $50', 'Per Unit Avg > $50'],
            [$totalOverCount, SanitizeData::currency(round($overAverage)), $totalOver50Count, SanitizeData::currency(round($over50Average))]
        ];
        return [
            'table'     => $items,
            'summary'    => $offset_summary
        ];
    }

}
```

**secondExport**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\UnitTypeDetail;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;

class OffsetSummaryExport implements FromArray
{
    protected $property;

    public function __construct($property)
    {
        $this->property = $property;
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        $unitTypeDetails = UnitTypeDetail::where('property_id',$this->property->id)
            ->get();

        $unitTypes[] = [
            'Unit Type',
            'Rent'
        ];
        foreach($unitTypeDetails as $uk => $uv){
            $unitTypes[] = [
                $uv->unit_type,
                $uv->rent
            ];
        }
        $unitType_data[] = $unitTypes;
        $unitType_data[] = [
            '',
            ''
        ];
        $unitType_data[] = [
            'Rate',
            $this->property->rate.'%'
        ];

        return $unitType_data;
    }
}
```

**Main Requirements**

Here, on class `OffetTableExport` you could see an array `offset_summary`, and I need this data to be shown on second sheet instead of first sheet. So, I tried to return this `offset_summary` with `$items` on first `OffetTableExport`.

And tried to retrieve it and add it onto the array of second sheet as:

```
$resp_data = new OffetTableExport($this->property, $this->mapped_columns);
$offset_summary = $offset + $resp_data['summary'];

$sheets = [
    $resp_data['table'],
    $offset_summary
];
```

But showing error, exactly on `$offset_summary = $offset + $resp_data['summary'];` this line as:

`Cannot use object of type App\Exports\OffetTableExport as array`

Update:

Strange but while dumping `resp_data` it shows:

```
App\Exports\OffetTableExport {#1789 ▼
  #property: App\Models\Property {#1657 ▼
    #table: "properties"
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: array:4 [▶]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:16 [▶]
    #original: array:16 [▶]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
  }
  #mapped_columns: array:10 [▼
    0 => "pms_unit_type"
    1 => "sqft"
    2 => "unit_count"
    3 => "unit_type"
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => "pricing_offset"
    8 => null
    9 => null
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the output `dd($resp_data);`?

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG I have updated it on the question, could you please take a look.

Comment: `$resp_data` and `$offset` in your `sheet()` method are only instances of the `OffsetSummaryExport` and `OffetTableExport` classes **before** the worksheet is created. The values aren't calculated yet so you can't pass data from one sheet to the other in that way.

Comment: @IGP any suggestion on how could I achieve that one?

Comment: @SarojShrestha  Either calculate the values again in the second sheet or use an event like `BeforeWriting` in `FloorPlanExport` to access the `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet` and manually copy the values from one worksheet/cell to the other (assuming you know where in the spreadsheet those values you need will be). If the values are present on both sheets and you know where they are, you could also use formulas