# color whole td column based on properties of th

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, laravel

So I have this table:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th style="width: 40%; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">Nr.<br> crt.</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; width: 210%; height: 25; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">Asistent</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; width: 210%; height: 25; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">Ambulantier</th>
    <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">Ambulanta</th>
    @foreach($dates as $date)
    @if($date['day_name'] == 'S' || $date['day_name'] == 'D')
    <th style="width: 40%; text-align: center; vertical-align: center; font-weight: bold; color: red;">{{$date['day']}}<br> {{$date['day_name']}}</th>
    @else
    <th style="width: 40%; text-align: center; vertical-align: center; font-weight: bold;">{{$date['day']}}<br> {{$date['day_name']}}</th>
    @endif
    @endforeach
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($interventions as $intervention)
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>{{$intervention->employee_one->name}}</td>
<td>{{$intervention->employee_two->name}}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

And this is what is generating:
[image]

As you can see, some numbers in the header have the red color. How can I color the WHOLE column with red if the respective `<th>` is also red?

I was thinking to use js, and it would look something like this (just an idea, not the actual code lol):

```
if(header(current_td).hasProperty('color: red')) {
   apply(color.red);
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `colgroup` as such:

```
<style>
.red-background {
background-color: red;
}
</style>
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
<col>

@foreach($dates as $date)
    @if($date['day_name'] == 'S' || $date['day_name'] == 'D')
<col class="red-background ">
    
    @else
<col>
  
    @endif
    @endforeach

  </colgroup>

<thead>
<tr>
    <th style="width: 40%; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">Nr.<br> crt.</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; width: 210%; height: 25; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">Asistent</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold; width: 210%; height: 25; text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">Ambulantier</th>
    <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">Ambulanta</th>
    @foreach($dates as $date)
 
    <th style="width: 40%; text-align: center; vertical-align: center; font-weight: bold;">{{$date['day']}}<br> {{$date['day_name']}}</th>
    

    @endforeach
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($interventions as $intervention)
<tr>
<td>0</td>
<td>{{$intervention->employee_one->name}}</td>
<td>{{$intervention->employee_two->name}}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hmm for some reason it's not coloring any column at all, not even the numbers

Comment: Do you intend to color the entire background or just the text?

Comment: the entire background. take as an example 01 S and 02 D. all the cells below them should have red background

Comment: I have updated my answer. I made a little error.

Comment: ah alright, your solution works well on a html page, but not on laravel excel. I am using a blade view to generate a table in excel and seems like styling like this doesn't work.. have you got any experience with laravel excel by any chance?

Comment: I don't have any experience with laravel excel but you can reference this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65376745/laravel-excel-style-with-css-not-working-while-exporting-view). Might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than formatting each individual cell, `colgroup` allows you to apply formatting to a all the cells in a columns instead.

```css
.highlight{
    background-color: #ffe8d4;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col class="highlight" />
        <col />
        <col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

```js
const trs = document.querySelectorAll('#table tr')
const ths = document.querySelectorAll('#table th')

for (let i = 1; i < trs.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < ths.length; j++) {
    if (ths[j].style.color == "red") {
      trs[i].children[j].style.color = "red"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th style="color: red;">C</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only JS with inline style, you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = () => {
        const ths = document.querySelectorAll('thead tr th');
        for (var i = 0; i < ths.length; i++) {
            if (ths[i].style.color === "red") {
                const trs = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
                for (tr of trs) {
                    tr.children[i].style.color = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```